# Timidity - Do I need it in this situation?

Tags: midi, lmms

I'm a musician, and have been looking for a simple way (no JACK) to play multi-track MIDI files on my main laptop.

I got turned on to Timidity, and it worked with varying degrees of success.

Now, I found LMMS - and I'm using a SoundFont. I also will be using Hardware MIDI devices (no SoundFonts).

I uninstalled Timidity - purge, etc - yet still still see a lot of files left behind with that name. Not large - but it bothers my OCD :)

If I'm happy with what LMMS is doing - with my SoundFonts - do I need ANY trace of Timidity? Or is it working in the back-end?

Comment: How have you installed & uninstalled timidity?

Comment: Installed it with apt-get - uninstalled it with the examples on this page - removing the daemon, purging, etc.  It's not running - but - when I search for file names - a few show up. http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/t/timidity-daemon/uninstall/index.html

Comment: What file names?

Comment: Just filenames in /  - see picture... https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4qgp0o9x3qaxc9/tim.png?dl=0